# Warning: Submit for login review .some of the permissions have not been approved for use by Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing an app using Facebook's login function. The application needs the user's friend list and "publish_actions" permissions. I have read Facebook's documentation and they clearly say that you have to submit your app for review, as well as the ".apk" file. I am confused because my app is still in developing mode. What to do ??

Answer (score 1):

according to new facebook sdk, you need to submit your app for review if you are publishing anything. after facebook approval you can upload picture by using any login. you can check this link for review process

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

https://github.com/sauce/guide/wiki/Facebook's-approval-process

Comment: Thanx ravi but my question is that should i submit apk file 
See this link please.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/#instructions

Comment: you can publish everything from your test account, that is from which you have registerd you application. but for other users you need approval from facebook, and yes for approval you need to submit apk, but right now for development purpose no need to take any approval.

Comment: but i am not getting any user's friend list.

Comment: for friend list facebook has done some changes in new sdk, i think you should refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u

Comment: you should read answer in the link i have given. you will get to know why you are getting { "data": [ ] }

Comment: exaclty what i am getting

{
  "data": [
  ]
}

and i also want to access a list of non app using friend ,and the solution for that question is to submitt review.

Comment: So! facebook will take couple of days to review your submission and we received an acknowlment via mail.